# Output from openssl_random_pseudo_bytes

Tags: php, encryption, hash

I'm planning to generate and store salt in database and pass it back to UI. I'm using [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) function.  Looking at the salt result I see following in PHP debug window

[image]

and the following in database record

[image]

I'm planning to recreate hash on client-side using this salt.

I'm curious if this random string of is okay to work with when passing it back and forth from server to UI?  Or should this be encoded before passing it back and forth?

Following is database column definition for SALT column
[image]

Comment: What is your column definition in the database?

Comment: Updated my answer with details. I'm guessing I might need to change Character set property?

Comment: You are storing binary data in a `VARCHAR` column. Try using `BINARY` type instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the column type to `VARBINARY` (or just `BINARY` if the length is fixed) instead of `VARCHAR`. Since the contents of the column are not meant to represent text, binary data types will be more efficient.

In any case, as long as there are no misconfiguration problem you should have no *correctness* issues in your application even with the column having its current data type.

Comment: I was confused as to how I would append binary to a string that I would like to hash. Looks like I need to encode binary output using `base64_encode` and then I can append it to string I'm trying to hash. Is that correct? Source: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode